# "Cannot refer to a non-final variable" from action handler?

Tags: java, oop, object, reference, jframe

I promise that I have read innumerable posts about this so I am guessing I cannot translate what I read to what I am trying to do. First the narrative. At the basis, what I wish to do is develop a list of objects in my example the objects are cars. The list of cars is displayed in my main window. When I want to add a new car, I open a dialog to set the attributes and create it.

The problem is I keep runnning in circles with the object references. I'vre tried creating subclasses with public methods and passing objects in constructors. These attempts result in errors about non-static fields or non-final variables. If I could just see a solid example of how to make the references, I think the rest would fall into place.

the object

```
public class Car {
private String size;

public Car(String sizeIn){
    this.size = sizeIn;
}   
public void setSize(String sizeIn){
    this.size = sizeIn;
}
public String getSize(){
    return this.size;
}
public String toString(){
    return this.size;
}
}
```

main window

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JList;

public class MainGUI {

private JFrame frame;
private LinkedList<Car> carList;
private DefaultListModel model;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainGUI window = new MainGUI();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public MainGUI() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JButton btnAddCar = new JButton("Add Car");
    btnAddCar.addActionListener(new EditLauncher());
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAddCar, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JList list = new JList(model);
    frame.getContentPane().add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void addCar(String size){
    Car car = new Car(size);
    carList.add(car);
    model.addElement(car);
    frame.getContentPane().invalidate();
    frame.getContentPane().validate();
}

public class EditLauncher implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

}
```

the dialog

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class EditDialog extends JDialog {

private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
private JTextField fldSize;
private MainGUI mainGUI;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        EditDialog dialog = new EditDialog(mainGUI); //<<ERROR - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mainGU
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public EditDialog(MainGUI mainGUI) {
    this.mainGUI = mainGUI;
    setBounds(100, 100, 225, 125);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    contentPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JLabel lblSize = new JLabel("Size");
    contentPanel.add(lblSize);
    fldSize = new JTextField();
    contentPanel.add(fldSize);
    fldSize.setColumns(10);

    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
    buttonPane.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    getContentPane().add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
    okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainGUI.addCar(fldSize.getText()); // << ERROR Cannot refer to a non-final variable mainGUI inside an inner class defined in a different method
        }
    });
    okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
    buttonPane.add(okButton);
    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);

    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
    buttonPane.add(cancelButton);

}

}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem, exactly? What lines of code aren't working as you think they should? And no, please, don't tell that the whole 50+ lines are the "problem" :)

Comment: On a very quick read-through … I don't see where any carList is being constructed, either? (should probably be in the constructor for the MainGUI glass that owns the reference)

Answer (score 6):

#### For "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field mainGUI"

The problem is (EditDialogs) `main` is static and can therefor only access static members or a member of an explicit object instance (e.g. `object.member` form). In this case, `mainGUI` is not a static member and therefor cannot be accessed: which is fine, because no MainGUI instance is created if that "main" is called! (Remember, *only one `main` is used* each time the application is launched! Get rid of the "main" in EditDialog to avoid this confusion.)

Instead, consider this (but *please see the comment by Dave* for a better approach entirely!):

```
btnAddCar.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        EditDialog dialog = new EditDialog(MainGUI.this);
        dialog.show(); // or whatever
    }
});
```

#### For "Cannot refer to a non-final variable mainGUI inside an inner class defined in a different method"

The error is because only member variables (of the enclosing type) or "final" local variables can be used from within an anonymous inner type (`new ActionListener() { ... }`).

Now, one might go "but mainGUI is a member variable!"

Well, it is, *but* it is being *shadowed* by a local variable with the same name (`this.mainGUI` vs `mainGUI`). Here are the solutions I know of:

1. Change the local variable name to avoid the shadowing: `public EditDialog(MainGUI theMainGUI) ...`
2. Qualify `mainGUI` to tell Java the member variable is desired, which bypasses the shadowing: `EditDialog.this.mainGUI.addCar(...)`, where `EditDialog` is the name of the enclosing type. (This same approach was done above for `MainGUI.this`.)
3. Annotate the `mainGUI` *parameter* with `final`: `public EditDialog(final MainGUI mainGUI) ...`. The member variable will still be shadowed, but the local variable will meet the access requirements as it's "final".

Happy coding.

Comment: Another suggestion -- separate your model and view.  By calling `addCar()` on the GUI class from the Dialog, you are modifying the model through the view.  It's preferable to modify the model directly.  Look at the Model-View-Controller design pattern.